# TinyMCE editor dislikes being moved around

Tags: html, dom, tinymce

On a page I have, I need to move TinyMCE editors in the DOM tree once in a while. However, for some reason, the editor doesn't like it: it clears itself completely and becomes unusable. As far as I can see, this behavior is consistent between Safari 4 and Firefox 3.6, but not Internet Explorer 7/8. [Here's an example](http://www.laissemoichercherca.com/%7Efelix/documents/tinymce/tinymce.html).

It truly is annoying to do something that works in Internet Explorer but not with more appreciable browsers. Is there something I missed in the docs about never trying to move an editor in the DOM tree? Is there some kind of workaround?

Comment: Could it be all the event handlers lose being bound to the elements when it is moved?

Comment: @alex: Unlikely. Event listeners on elements are maintained even if they're not rooted to the document.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I just remembered you lost them when using `innerHTML`. But I just checked your source, and you are using proper DOM methods. Does CKeditor do the same thing

Comment: @alex: I don't know. I'm not home right now, so I'll check that later. If CKEditor does it better I guess I'll just forget about TinyMCE.

Comment: I've switched to CKeditor after a lot of pain caused by others. It's got a large footprint, but it's pretty good.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a browser bug/issue not a problem with TinyMCE. It's impossible to retain iframe contents in some browsers since once you remove the node from the dom the document/window unloads. I suggest first removing the editor instance then re-adding it instead of moving it in the DOM.

Comment: That was what I've been doing initially, but I was having problems with `document_base_url` messing up my images on save. That was actually unrelated and I've fixed it (with `convert_urls` to `false`). But oh well, it works, and you deserve some rep.

Comment: Can't get a better answer than one from the main developer of TinyMCE! +1

Answer (score 10):

Had the same issue and here's how I resolved it...

**Create the issue**

I use jquery to move the dom element that contains the tinymce editor that causes it to lose all it's contents:

```
$('.form-group:last').after($('.form-group:first'))
```

After this point, the editor's iframe contents are removed.

**The Solution**

```
var textareaId = 'id_of_textarea';
tinyMCE.get(textareaId).remove();
tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddEditor", false, textareaId);
```

There are times when the editor will add the iframe back, but not be visible.  If that's the case, unhide the container:

```
$textarea = $('#' + textareaId)
$textarea.closest('.mce-tinymce.mce-container').show()
```

Note, this is using tinymce 4.x.