# Remove tinymce 4 editor from set of editors

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, tinymce-4

I'm creating a custom AngularJS directive that wraps a tinymce 4 editor.
The issue arises when I try to remove a tinymce editor from a set of other tinymce editors. Please, check the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RamanChodzka/a8dUp/63/). Here try to remove the first or the second editor, and following editors become broken.

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.editors = [{}, {}, {}];
    $scope.removeEditorByIndex = function (index) {
        $scope.editors.splice(index, 1);
    };
});
app.directive('myEditor', function () {
    var uniqueId = 0;
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: true,
        template: '<textarea></textarea>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            var id = 'myEditor_' + uniqueId++;
            element.find('textarea').attr('id', id);
            tinymce.init({
                selector: '#' + id
            });

            //where in AngularJS should I place the following lines?
            //tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', false, id);
            //tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddEditor', false, id);
        }
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        Try removing the first editor. You will see that next editors become unusable.
        <div ng-repeat="editor in editors">
            <button ng-click="removeEditorByIndex($index)">Remove editor #{{$index + 1}}</button>
            <my-editor ng-model="text"></my-editor>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The reason for this is that after removing an element from `$scope.editors`, angular removes each subsequent editor and appends it again at the place of the removed editor (internally angular calls jQuery `.after()`). And

> It's impossible to retain iframe contents in some browsers since once
>   you remove the node from the dom the document/window unloads

(taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2542043/1492792)).

To fix broken editor I should call:

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', false, id);
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddEditor', false, id);
```

(calling these two lines one after another will do)

Where should I put these reinitializing lines? What is the appropriate angularish way of calling these lines?

N.B. I might also switch to the inline mode of tinymce editor which does not rely upon iframe. But that would bring a major inconvenience: styles from the editor will intersect with styles from the page. This option is therefore not acceptable.

Comment: Hey so I have sort of an orthogonal answer if you'd like me to post it.  I found an angular wrapper/directive for CKEditor which in my opinion is a little nicer than TinyMCE anyhow, if you'd like I can share the code (not sure that I have the original reference/link though).

Comment: I assume the two lines would need to be called within the delete function.  The tricky part will be passing in the `id`.

Comment: @shaunhusain looks like CKEditor relies on iframes too. http://ckeditor.com/demo

Comment: @rGil nice idea. I could establish a cache of editor ids that are still present on the page. A quick proof of concept http://jsfiddle.net/RamanChodzka/a8dUp/68/

Comment: You could run tinyMCE in inline mode, why use iframes if you don't have to?

Comment: Also, this works better in for example FF: `tinyMCE.editors[id].execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', false, id);`

Comment: @ChristofferBubach I made an explanation in my question why inline mode is not an option for me. Using inline mode could cause styles conflicts.

Comment: @ChristofferBubach could you please explain why `tinyMCE.editors[id].execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', false, id);` works better in FF?

Comment: Oh, ok. Well, I'm not sure why, but nothing happens in FF without it. I guess you have to tell which editor you want to perform the execCommand call.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really have to use AngularJS for this otherwise quite simple thing - if so you will have to try and extract the editor content with something like

`content[] = tinymce.get(id).getContent();`

and make sure to discard the right content before putting it back with

`tinymce.get(id).setContent(content[i]);`

once you added the editor back.

Comment: There are no issues with content. It's stored in the $scope. The issue is that editors become broken (in FF 8.0.1 editors get broken too) -- that's because of iframes unload. So to fix editors I have to reinitialize them. The question is what is the right place in an AngularJS directive to put those reinitializing lines.

Comment: Doesn't AngularJS change the scope ID's when you splice one out? If so, how can it map the content to an old editor. I've tried many variations of your code, and at best I can reinitalize with right content but the old broken editors will also still show up below or above the working. So I think you might need to remap the editor id's with the scope id's before you can reinit. or maybe I should just give up and see if someone else with actual AngularJS knowlegde can help instead

Comment: Actually, rGil gave an idea where I should place reinitializing lines. And I updated my jsfiddle jsfiddle.net/RamanChodzka/a8dUp/68 . Check comments below my question. Looks like the fiddle works.

Comment: indeed, that seem to work fine. a bit annoying for me, since i tried something similar as one of my first attempts. :P