# How do you make a TinyMCE editor to work again after running tinyMCE.triggerSave()?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4, richtext

I am sending input to my backend server via ajax. Part of the input is coming from a TinyMCE rich text editor. I have run `tinyMCE.triggerSave()` to make it so that I can grab the value from the initial textarea rather than trying to figure out the dynamically created tinyMCE editor key. The issue is that when I do this, it makes all the tinyMCE rich text editors unresponsive to editing attempts. I cannot click in the text area.

## Edit

---

I had a method that was reinitializing all the editors. That is what one of the answers was trying to go with. However, this is not the issue I have found. The issues seems to be when I try to sort the cards that contain the editors. The cards are sorted by the dates that are in them. This is what is making the editors uneditable. I wish I knew a better way to sort them. Do I need to "close" the editors then reinitalize them?

Here is the editor script

```
/**
 * Sort contact history cards by the date they show.
 */
const sortHistories = () => {
    $(".history-card").sort((first, second) => {
        const firstDate = Date.parse($(first).attr('data-history-date'));
        const secondDate = Date.parse($(second).attr('data-history-date'));
        return (firstDate > secondDate) ? -1 : (firstDate < secondDate) ? 1 : 0;
    }).appendTo($("#history-cards"));
};
```

Comment: I have found a solution to this likely as a duplication of this issue
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2542043/4289616

Answer (score 1):

When you call `triggerSave()` all that TinyMCE is doing is taking the current contents of TinyMCE and pushing it into the underlying `textarea`.

I have made a TinyMCE Fiddle to show this:

https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/F3haab/1

If you edit the content in the editor and click the first button you will see that the `getContent()` API call sees the updates but the underlying `textarea` will not be updated.  If you click the second button this first calls `triggerSave()` and then the same method as the first button.  The end result of the second button shows that `triggerSave()` syncs the `textarea` with the editor.

None of this activity in and of itself does anything to the functioning of the editor.

Why are you trying to reinitialize the editors?  Did you first `remove()` the editors?  I don't think the simple act of submitting the content would require you to have to `remove()` and re `init()` the editors so there could be something else in play on the page you have not described?

Comment: I have multiple editors, and my thinking was that if I reinitialize them it would make them editable again since without this method it was simply making them uneditbale.

Comment: I have made a significant step to trying to debug this.